# Getting OOM(Java out of memory) issue while doing bulk delete operation from java in MongoTemplate method

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, out-of-memory, mongotemplate

Created a scheduler to delete the older records from mongoDB, which runs once a day but getting OOM issue while deleting the records from DB.

We are getting more than 50K records to get deleted

The method is like below

```
@Override
    public void purgeLteTimeBlock(Long timeBlock) {
        Query query = new Query();
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where(Constants.TIME_BLOCK).lte(timeBlock));
        mongoTemplate.findAllAndRemove(query, abcEntity.class);
    }
```

From our observation we have found that mongoTemplate provides 3 findAllAndRemove methods and each of them returning the list of objects which are getting deleted.
so we thought that this might be the reason of getting OOM(out of memory issue) because it's giving back more than 50K records in a code

So is there any solution to handle this kind of delete operations from mongoDB?

Comment: Just use `remove` instead of `findAllAndRemove`.

Comment: Thnaks, it worked.